# Bootstrap is-invalid and is-valid not working correct with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter php frame work with ajax.

When I submit my form through ajax and there is a form error the input colors change.

[image]

How ever because the user agents username input has all ready got value in it. It changes to green like in this image below

But when I add this

```
if ($('#input-' + key).length >= 1) {
    $('#input-' + key).val($('#input-' + key).val());
    $('#input-' + key).removeClass('is-invalid');
}
```

It removes the other form inputs `is-invalid` it should only remove the ones that have set value AS SHOWN IN IMAGE AT BOTTOM

> Question How can I make sure that if the input has a set value in it that class `is-invalid` would change to `is-valid` but the other empty inputs class `is-invalid` will stay set.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#error').html(" ");

    $('#form-submit-button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('agent/register/validate');?>", 
            data: $("#agent-register-form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('#input-' + key).addClass('is-invalid');

                    if ($('#input-' + key).length >= 1) {
                        $('#input-' + key).val($('#input-' + key).val());
                        $('#input-' + key).removeClass('is-invalid');
                    }

                    $('#input-' + key).parents('.form-group').find('#error').html(value);
                });
            }
        });
    });

    $('#agent-register-form input').on('keyup', function () { 
        $(this).removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
        $(this).parents('.form-group').find('#error').html(" ");
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check adding this code in your success function of ajax call.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#error').html(" ");

    $('#form-submit-button').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('agent/register/validate');?>",
        data: $("#agent-register-form").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('#input-' + key).addClass('is-invalid');

            if ($('#input-' + key).val().length >= 1) {
              $('#input-' + key).removeClass('is-invalid');
            }

            $('#input-' + key).parents('.form-group').find('#error').html(value);
          });
        }
      });
    });

    $('#agent-register-form input').on('keyup', function() {
      $(this).removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
      $(this).parents('.form-group').find('#error').html(" ");
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

Comment: Sorry does not help

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved now was checking the wrong each part need to add if statement below.

```
if (data['error'] == true) {

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if (value === ""){
             $('#input-' + key).addClass('is-valid'); 
        } else {
             $('#input-' + key).addClass('is-invalid');
        }
    });

}
```